# Different Credentials on Domain PC and SharePoint site. Who's Credentials are used for HTTP Request?

Tags: http, authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, request

Given a SharePoint 2010 site that uses Windows Authentication, if UserA logs onto a PC on the domain, then UserB uses the PC to log into the SharePoint site with domain credentials, then loads a WebPart which sends an HTTP request out to the internet, who's credentials are being used for the HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

while sending the HTTP Request the credentials of the user who is currently logged on to the SharePoint Site will be used.
SharePoint provides the ease of auto login if the site and the SharePoint lies in the same domain but in case the user logs out and a new users logs in instead, the new users credentials will be used, it has nothing to with who is logged on to the system.

Thanks

Sahil

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do something like this:

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 webClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
 byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData("address");
```

Neither UserA nor UserB credentials will be used.

If you use default NTLM Windows authentication protocol it is impossible to do any external (to any other computer) request under identity of logged user.

If your domain is configured to use Kerberos protocol then SP may be able (according the Kerberos configuration) to do externall call under the identity of logged user service (e.g. HTTP) running on another computer.

If you wrap calling the HTTP request to SPUtility.RunWithElevatedPriviliges request will be done under the identity of SharePoint system account (something like sp_service).